# Load data from json file with listAction on jTable

Tags: json, jtable, load

I m a new bee in java...
cant work it out and i m sure its very easy so i was wondering if anyone can help me,,pleaseee...
so, i want to view my json data in html using jTable pluging ,,,please some help 
using netbeans my test.json file is in the format

```
 {
"Result": "OK",
"TotalRecordCount": 23,
"Records": [
    {
        "vEmail": "miad@gmail1.com",
        "vUserName": "admin",
        "nDepartmentId": "652",
        "nEnabled": "1",
        "department": 62,
        "vFatherName": "mixalis",
        "vSurname": "mixalis",
        "vAfm": "5678678",
        "vUsertype": "",
        "vName": "mixalis",
        "nId": "5651",
        "rolesDesc": ""
    },
```

and so on on my code usng the listAction url and the load method but i m missing smthg here??what is it?is it a bracket?is it a plane?is it a train?no its superman..(that was a joke),
my code

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
    <link href="/test/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <!-- Include jTable script file. -->
    <script src="/test/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Kyriakos Test with Table of Persons',
        actions: {
            listAction: '/test/test.json'               
        },
        fields: {
            PersonId: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            vEmail: {
                title: 'Email',
                width: '8.3%'
            },
            vUserName: {
                title: 'User Name',
                width: '8.3%'
            },
            nDepartment: {
                title: 'Department',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            nEnabled: {
                title: 'Enabled',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            department: {
                title: 'Department',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vFatherName: {
                title: 'Father Name',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vSurname: {
                title: 'Surname',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vAfm: {
                title: 'Afm',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vUsertype: {
                title: 'User Type',
                width: '8.3%'
                 },
            vName: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '8.3%'
                 },
            nId: {
                title: 'Id',
                width: '8.3%'
                 },
            rolesDesc: {
                title: 'Roles Desc',
                width: '8.3%'

          }

        }
      $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
   });
});
```

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

what were?? oohh i m confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       <html>
       <head>
       <title></title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
       <link href="/test/css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       <script src="/test/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
       <script src="/test/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/test/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
       <!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
       <link href="/test/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
       <!-- Include jTable script file. -->
       <script src="/test/jtable/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Kyriakos Test with Table of Persons',
        actions: {
           listAction: '/test/test.json',
            createAction: '/GettingStarted/CreatePerson',
            updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
            deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'           
        },
        fields: {
            PersonId: {
                key: true,
                list: false
            },
            vEmail: {
                title: 'Email',
                width: '8.3%'
            },
            vUserName: {
                title: 'User Name',
                width: '8.3%'
            },
            nDepartment: {
                title: 'Department',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            nEnabled: {
                title: 'Enabled',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            department: {
                title: 'Department',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vFatherName: {
                title: 'Father Name',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vSurname: {
                title: 'Surname',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vAfm: {
                title: 'Afm',
                width: '8.3%'
                },
            vUsertype: {
                title: 'User Type',
                width: '8.3%'
                 },
            vName: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '8.3%'
                 },
            nId: {
                title: 'Id',
                width: '8.3%'
                 },
            rolesDesc: {
                title: 'Roles Desc',
                width: '8.3%'

          }

        }

      });
    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
   });

   </script>     

   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```